# Can't check when NSDate is NULL

Tags: ios, nsdate

I create an entity named "NoteEntity" in CoreData and generate NSManageObject subclass

```
@interface NoteEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * time;
@end
```

Then I addObserver to check time change when select object:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"noteEntity.time" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:KNoteEntityTime];
```

Observer Code:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ( context == KNoteEntityTime ) {

        NSDate *oldTime = (NSDate *)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] ;
        if (oldTime != NULL) {
            NSLog(@"CHANGE:From %@ - %@",oldTime,self.noteEntity.time);

        }

    }

    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

I need to check if noteEntity.time change from NULL but the if (oldTime != NULL) or if(oldTime) not WORK, here is the log

```
CHANGE:From <null> - (null)
CHANGE:From <null> - 2013-07-29 10:15:58 +0000
```

Please help me find out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @isaach1000 Nah, those are the same. The problem is that `<null>` is not the description of `nil` or `Nil` or `NULL`, but that of `NSNull`. Try `if (![oldTime isEqual:[NSNull null]])` instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much @H2CO3 Please make it as an answer

Comment: You're welcome, done. It's worth playing around a bit with the description of objects so you get used to what looks like what when printed/logged using `NSLog(@"%@")`. Also, make sure to pay attention to subtle details like angle brackets versus regular parentheses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<null>` is the description of `NSNull`, not that of `nil` (or `Nil` or `NULL` which are the same). Try

```
if (![oldTime isEqual:[NSNull null]])
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (![oldTime isEqual:[NSNull null]]) { ... }
```

Objects in the containers (NSArray, NSDictionary etc) can not be nil or null in objective c

Comment: `if (oldTime != [NSNull null])` is not reliable. Also note that `- [NSDictionary objectForKey:]` may return `nil` (unlike `- [NSArray objectAtIndex:]`).

Comment: @H2CO3 It actually is. `NSNull` is a singleton with a fixed address, so simple pointer comparison does work.

Comment: @H2CO3 NSDictionary returns nil only if the key is not present in the dictionary. You cannot store nil "objects" in the dictionary.

Comment: @fishinear I know how `NSDictionary` works, and I didn't write "you can store `nil` in an `NSDictionary`". I wrote that "`- [NSDictionary objectForKey:]` may return `nil`". Don't twist my words. And don't teach me Cocoa/Objective-C.

Comment: @JustSid Is that documented? (**I know it is actually implemented as a singleton,** but if that isn't documented, then the pointer comparison isn't safe, as implementation details may change in the future. The "don't teach me Cocoa/Objective-C" part concerns you as well.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I thought you reacted because you disagreed with the OP's statement: "Objects in the containers can not be nil or null". I simply tried to point out that that statement is correct.

Comment: @fishinear No, I was only clarifying that it *may* return `nil`, since torip3ng's answer suggests that the `nil`-check is superfluous, which is only true in the case of arrays, not dictionaries.

Comment: @H2CO3 If I remember correctly, there was some documentation that mentioned it somewhere (I think it was the collection classes guide, but don't take my word for it). But I know that I've seen it in sample code already. By the way, can I interest you in my new "Teaching Cocoa/Objective-C to SO users" course? :p

Comment: @JustSid I couldn't see the forest for the trees, it's right in the first sentence of the `NSNull` documentation. (The direct pointer comparison on objects is still something I dislike, though.) As to the course: is it free?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(yourdate){
```

//Set date
}else{
  //Not set date
}